# On a positive semidefinite infinite matrix coming from a ordinary differental equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $F: B\rightarrow  R$ be the real analytic real valued  function defined on an open ball  $B\subset C^2$ by:
\begin{equation}%\label{diastcal}
F(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k\left((z_1+\bar z_1)^2+(z_2+\bar z_2)^2\right)^k,\nonumber
\end{equation}
where $c_k=\frac{y^{(2k)}(0)}{(2k)!}$ and $y^{(2k)}$ is the $2k$-th derivative of the real analytic  function $y: R\rightarrow R$ which satisfies the differential equation:
\begin{equation}
(y'/r)y''=e^y,\nonumber
\end{equation}
with initial conditions
\begin{equation}
y'(0)=0,\ y''(0)=e^{y(0)/2}.\nonumber
\end{equation}

We can write a power expansion of $F$ in the variables $z$ and $\bar z$:
$$F(z,\bar z)=\sum_{j,k=0}^{\infty}a_{jk}z_1^{m_{j, 1}}z_2^{m_{j, 2}}\bar z_1^{m_{k, 1}}\bar z_2^{m_{k, 2}}$$
where $(m_{j,1}, m_{j,2})$ are couples of nonnegative integers, ordered in such a way that $(m_{j,1}, m_{j,2})\leq (m_{j+1,1}, m_{j+1,2})$ if $m_{j,1}+m_{j,2}\leq m_{j+1,1}+m_{j+1,2}$ and for all the couples with $m_{j,1}+m_{j,2}= m_{j+1,1}+m_{j+1,2}$ we use the lexicographic order. For example,
we have,
$(0, 0)<(1, 0)<(0, 1)<(2, 0)<(1, 1)<(0, 2)$
and so on.

Consider the $\infty\times \infty$ matrix $A=(a_{jk})_{j,k=1,2,\dots}$, i.e. the matrix of coefficients in the power expansion above where the first row and first column have been deleted.

Question: 
Is $A$ a positive semidefinite matrix?